# remove/isolate days when there is no change (in pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have annual hourly energy data for two AC systems for two hotel rooms. I want to figure out when the rooms were occupied or not by isolating/removing the days when the ac was not used for 24 hours.

I did `df[df.Meter2334Diff > 0.1]` for one room which gives me all the hours when AC was turned on, however it removes the hours of the days when the room was most likely occupied and the AC was turned off. This is where my knowledge stops. I therefore enquire the assistance from the oracles of the internet.
[image: Dataframe]
my dataframe above
[image: df[df.Meter2334Diff > 0.1]]
results after `df[df.Meter2334Diff > 0.1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've interpreted your question correctly, you want to extract all the days from the dataframe where the `Meter2334Diff` value was zero?

As your data is currently has a frequency of every hour, we can resample it in pandas using the `resample()` function. To `resample()` we can pass the `freq` parameter which tells pandas at what time interval to aggregate the data. There are lots of options ([see the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)) but in your case we can set `freq='D'` to group by day.

Then we can calculate the sum of that day for the `Meter2334Diff` column. If we then filter out the days that have a value == 0 (obviously without knowledge of your dataset  etc I don't know whether 0 is the correct value).

```
total_daily_meter_diff = df.resample('D')['Meter2334Diff'].sum()
days_less_than_cutoff = total_daily_meter_diff.query('MeterDiff2334 == 0')
```

We can then use these days to filter in the original dataset:

```
df.loc[df.index.floor('D').isin(days_less_than_cutoff) , :]
```

Comment: Thank you! 
.query was not recognized in my jupyter file, however I managed to do it with 
'df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
freq='D'
total_daily_meter_diff = df.resample('D')['Meter2334Diff'].sum()
total_daily_meter_diff[total_daily_meter_diff == 0]'